# Function result in null output in R?

Tags: r, if-statement, for-loop, dataset, user-defined-functions

I have dataset names like

```
no   names
1    Anu
2    Bhanwarlal
3    Millennium
4    NA
5    Mushkil
6    NA
7    Niraj
8     NA
9    Dharmender
10    S
11    Hocalwire
12    Mansoor

girl
no   name
1    Anu
2    Komal
3    Piyu

boy 
no   name
1    Amit
2    Niraj
3    Dharmendra
4    Monsoor
5    Akash
```

The sample dataset can be created as:

```
# set up a vector of names
names <- c('Anu', 'Bhanwarlal', 'Komal', NA, 'Mushkil', NA, 'Niraj', NA, 'Dharmendra', 'S', 'Amit', 'Monsoor')
# set up a vector of female names
girls <- c('Anu', 'Komal', 'Piyu')
# set up a vector of male names
boys <- c('Amit', 'Niraj', 'Dharmendra', 'Monsoor', 'Akash')
```

I have dataset names. If names is in boy or girl then assign Male or Female to that names by adding a column in names dataset.

```
gender <- function(names,boy,girl){
  for(i in 1:nrow(names)){
     if(names[i,1] %in% girl$name){
       names$gen[i] <- "Female"
     } else if(names[i,1] %in% boy$name){
       names$gen[i]<- "Male"
     } else
       names$gen[i] <- "NA"
   }
}

gen <- gender(names,boy,girl)
```

output :

```
> gen
NULL
```

What would be a probable mistake I can't find out.

Comment: Your function is missing a return value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is a quick way to do your analysis:

```
# names
names <- c('Anu', 'Bhanwarlal', 'Komal', NA, 'Mushkil', NA, 'Niraj', NA, 'Dharmendra', 'S', 'Amit', 'Monsoor')
girls <- c('Anu', 'Komal', 'Piyu', 'Anu')
boys <- c('Amit', 'Niraj', 'Dharmendra', 'Monsoor', 'Akash')

# dataframes
name <- tibble::data_frame(names, gen = NA)
girl <- tibble::data_frame(name = girls, gender = rep('Female', length(girls)))
boy <- tibble::data_frame(name = boys, gender = rep('Male', length(boys)))
map_names <- rbind(girl, boy)

# function
gender <- function(names, map_names){
    n <- nrow(names)
    for(i in seq_len(n)){
        k <- which(names[[i, 1]] == map_names$name)
        if (length(k) != 0) {
            if (length(k) > 1) {
                k <- k[1]
            }
            names[[2]][i] <- map_names$gender[k]    
        } else {
            names[[2]][i] <- 'NA'
        }  
    }
    colnames(names) <- c('names', 'gender')
    return(names)
}

#output
gen <- gender(name, map_names)
gen
# A tibble: 12 × 2
        names gender
        <chr>  <chr>
1         Anu Female
2  Bhanwarlal     NA
3       Komal Female
4        <NA>     NA
5     Mushkil     NA
6        <NA>     NA
7       Niraj   Male
8        <NA>     NA
9  Dharmendra   Male
10          S     NA
11       Amit   Male
12    Monsoor   Male
```

Comment: Getting the output. But for few names which are available in girl or boy resulting in NA. and with a warning message: In names[[2]][i] <- map_names$gender[k] : number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length.any solution to this problem.

Comment: Can you provide a reproducible example? It might be happening in cases where the names are repeated or duplicated. The `which` function will return a vector of length greater than 1 in such cases.

Comment: Yes, some names are repeating 2 or 3 times. Is there any option to provide a reproducible example. Can i use %in% instead of which in above code?

Comment: I used match instead of which function, this execute without any warning message

Comment: Can you modify your initial code and show how you have used `match` instead of `which`?

Comment: k <- which(names[[i, 1]] == map_names$name)                                                    k <- match(names[[i, 1]], map_names$name)                                                       like this i had used.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the answer by Jovial Mann, your problem is in not telling the user defined function that it should return any output. To fix that, just add `names` on the last row in your function and you should see some output.

Next, you can use 'sapply' function to avoid using for loop.

```
# set up a vector of names
names <- c('Anu', 'Bhanwarlal', 'Komal', NA, 'Mushkil', NA, 'Niraj', NA, 'Dharmendra', 'S', 'Amit', 'Monsoor')
# set up a vector of female names
girls <- c('Anu', 'Komal', 'Piyu')
# set up a vector of male names
boys <- c('Amit', 'Niraj', 'Dharmendra', 'Monsoor', 'Akash')

# create a gender assigning function
gender <- function(names, femaleNames, maleNames)
{
        # create a placeholder dataframe
        data <- data.frame(names = names, gender = NA)
        # when name is found in vector of female names, assign gender female
        data$gender[sapply(names,"%in%", femaleNames)] <- "Female"
        # when name is found in vector of male names, assign gender male
        data$gender[sapply(names, "%in%", maleNames)] <- "Male"
        # return data frame with names and gender
        data
}

# see the output
gender(names, girls, boys)
```

Comment: It,s working, but the problem is still there. For few names which are available in girls and boys data are resulting in NA

Comment: Can you provide and example of that behavior?

Comment: Shiv   Male
Anuj   <NA>
Amit   Male
Subhamoy   <NA>
Narendra   Male
Jawa   <NA>          
Sapnakapse   <NA>
 Venkata   <NA>
  Ajay   Male
Like Anuj, Subhamoy and Venkata are in boy data. But they are assigned NA.

Comment: I am not able to reproduce the behavior.. are you sure the names Subhamoy and Venkata are included in the boy names? Is their spelling really the same in names and boy names? Aren't there any special characters or trailing spaces?

Comment: Yes, both names are included in the boy names. No spelling mistake.